# Water simulation doesn't show shaded mesh in viewport

Tags: fluid-simulation

In Blender 3.1 I can't find the option to see my shaded liquid mesh in the viewport. All I see are coloured particles (left image), but as you can see on my right image it renders fine.

[image]

How can I see the render in the viewport and not the particle stream?

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file? It's rather hard to know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Done. Please note that theres no Bake included. Should be enough to quickly do a low res simulation at your end to be at the same point as me.

Comment: Select Domain and go to Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display as ... you have set Bounds ... set Textured. To hide "rainbow" particles go to Particle or Modifier properties and disable monitor icon.

Comment: @vklidu that's what I have technically mentioned in my answer... If the OP read it, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was I was still showing the liquid particles. Turning them off was the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @NiclasW. Ah well... By the looks of your question it felt like you couldn't see your sim, so I never mentioned particles. Anyways, at least you got your answer :-)

Comment: @vklidu post it as an answer to get it accepted, would help others

Comment: @vklidu Edited, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Particles display

If you want to make the particles disappear, you have two options:

[image][image]

Or if you want to do this:

You probably have accidentally set the Visibility to bounds:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not about baking. I already baked the simulation, and I also know how to change my particles. Also the mesh tab is activated. I want to shade my simulation, but can't get rid of the view I posted above.

Comment: @NiclasW. Check my edits.

Comment: Yes, I checked, but the problem weren't the bounds, but the particles from liquid occluding my mesh. Thank you.

Comment: @NiclasW. Well, I have mentioned hiding the particles. Though no problem, have fun

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> Select Domain and go to Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display as ... you have set Bounds ... set Textured. To hide "rainbow" particles go to Particle or Modifier properties and disable monitor icon.

Turning off particles was the solution. Thanks.